# How can I export some Blog posts from our Sql Server, to a file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, export, export-to-excel

We have a simple website that contains (take your pick, for this example) blog posts / q & a questions / whatever. People upload text (single sentences to paragraphs .. including some white listed/approved html).

I need to export this data into .. a file / something .. so I can give the data to someone else.

eg. sample schema

```
Id INT
Title VARCHAR(100)
UniqueUrl VARCHAR(100)
Content VARCHAR(MAX)
ModifiedOn DATETIME
PublishedOn DATETIME
CreatedByUserId INTEGER
```

Is there any way I can export this data into a format that is simple to give to another person to import? I have no idea what they will import it into .. so i was guessing a csv or excel format might be sufficient. That said, one of the fields contains VARCHAR(MAX) which can have paragraphs of text.

Anyone have any suggestions?

#### ##Update

I've tried

- `Tasks -> Export Data` : this always give me an error during the final step. Error message give's -nothing- about what happened. Total fail :(
- `Run my sql script -> save results as -> .txt or .csv` : file is created, but i just can't read the content .. especially since one of the fields is a `VARCHAR(MAX)` with the User Generated Content everywhere :(

Maybe export as `XML`?

> > What have you tried?

I'm not sure what other things I can try / what options there are, besides the two, above.

Comment: you can export data from a table many ways. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is going to the be the simplest solution here.  The line breaks will rip apart most csv readers, and the quotation marks will finish off the rest.

Comment: I ended up using BCP (command line) and the results using XML. win.